# Reselling Power Apps or a Power Apps Marketplace

Tags: powerapps

The company I am working with is looking to develop a Power App that integrates various Microsoft 365 features and maybe Trello.  I've been looking online, but I can't figure out if there is a way to sell Power Apps online, either in a Marketplace or if there is a way to transfer a Power App outside of your organisation into another one.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I looked into this once. IIRC, you can "sell" PowerApps online through either private sales or Microsoft [AppSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/appsource-overview).

**Private sales:**

1. You find your own customers
2. Create the PowerApp

   - Either just a raw .msapp file or .zip OR

     - Your customer can just "look under the hood" and make changes to the code
   - Using a Managed Solution

     - Packages any ancillary Flow's, Custom Connectors, etc.
     - Your customer cannot look at the code
   - Using an Unmanaged Solution

     - Packages any ancillary Flow's, Custom Connectors, etc.
     - You customer can make changes to the code
3. Distribute it to your customers, help them set it up, etc.

**AppSource:**

0. You / your org needs to be an Independent Service Vendor(ISV)
1. Its murky on whether you can sell PowerApps *Canvas* Apps* that use **any** data source (SQL, DB2, Sharepoint, etc.), or [only Canvas Apps that use DataVerse or Model-driven Apps (AKA: Dynamics365)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/marketplace-commercial-transaction-capabilities-and-considerations#determine-offer-type-and-pricing-plan)
2. Microsoft "finds your customers" (or at least helps)
3. Create the app using a Managed or Unmanaged Solution
4. I believe your customers can install the App directly into their own environment from AppSource

*only mention of the term "Canvas" in the ISV docs is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/test-drive-azure-subscription-setup)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking on AppSource.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=powerapps

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look on AppSource but that seems to have prerequisites that your app is a SaaS app and must use Azure AD.  It doesn't seem to cover applications that hook into Microsoft 365 components like Outlook, Calendar, Tasks, etc.  There is no official support for AppSource, it just passes you into Microsoft generic support, whom have no idea what AppSource or Power Apps are.

Answer (score -1):

1. Power apps runs in an environment-

   1.1. power apps is something like microsoft allows you to develop and share the applications within a specific environment. It is not something like a standalone or a web application which you can install or host in any machine.

   1.2. If you have an account provided by the organisation and the organisation has provided you an appropriate license to develop and share the application for power apps then, you can only use the application within that organisation specific environment as it uses connections and datasources allowed to your account which resides in company created environment scope.You cannot export and use the application outside because it will not be able to get the connections used in the aplication to manipulate or display the data.

Comment: Anyone can create a Canvas app in Tenant A (@abc.com), export the app then import it in Tenant B (@123.org). You just need to also setup the Data Sources/Flows/Custom Connectors/etc. in Tenant B. **Example**: Here is a [library of sample apps that you can install in your tenant](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Community-App-Samples/bd-p/AppFeedbackGallery)

Comment: @SeaDude I liked that you shared some samples with me. But, My question is how can someone access the data which is in company's scope. I don't think company will allow that to access their data by an outsider to establish the connection while importing the exported solution or app.

Comment: The OP asks `...if there is a way to sell Power Apps online...` and `...if there is a way to transfer a Power App outside of your organisation into another one...`. **Example2**: Vendor A creates a PowerApp Canvas app using Azure SQL as a data source. They create the SQL tables, schema, etc. and get it working. Customer B buys the app, schema, etc. from Vendor A. Customer proceeds to either import the app and SQL tables *themselves* or Vendor A can assist by being granted a guest / temp account in Customer B's tenant.

Comment: There are also things like [Azure B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/what-is-b2b) that allow Vendor A to host data and applications for Customer B, but I've not worked with that before.

Comment: Ohh I didn't aware of that thanks for elaborating :)